# How do multiple telephones (Landline/POTS) transmit over same line?

Tags: telephony

How multiple telephones(Landline) transmit signals simultaneously? How the bandwidth is divided individually to make transmission happen individually?

Comment: Is this question about a network you own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merging multiple individual signals/services/data paths together is called *multiplexing*. Depending how you actually do that there are several technologies:

- time division multiplexing (TDM) - there are distinctive time slots that iterate over the services (e.g. most ISDN variants)
- frequency division multiplexing (FDM) - each service uses a dedicated frequency band over copper (e.g. xDSL over POTS/ISDN)
- wavelength division multiplexing (WDM) - each service uses one or more dedicated wavelengths/colors over fiber (e.g. for SONET or Ethernet WAN/MAN)

When it comes to packet switching, multiplexing a large number of data streams comes naturally (essentially a kind of dynamic TDM).

For POTS landlines, both TDM and FDM are (were) used. Both usually exclude the use of additional FDM for DSL.